# How to apply Revit display settings in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Refer to the screenshots, in Revit, there are several settings that allow the texture/graphics to be changed.

[image: Visual Style]

[image: Detail Level]

May I know how can I set the same settings in Forge Viewer? I am using the up-to-date version of Forge. (v7)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be aware that the Forge viewer is basically domain agnostic and handles models from many widely differing domains, such as architecture and mechanical, and from a very large number of different seed file CAD design programs. Obviously it is impossible to build in full support for all viewing options of all CAD programs.

That said, the Forge viewer is originally based on the [three.js viewer](https://threejs.org) and provides full access to all view settings via JavaScript.

This enables you to adapt and modify it freely just as you wish, and thus to replicate the Revit view settings if you so desire.